# One row time lag using R

Tags: r, dataframe, time

I have a data  `df` as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3),
                 year=c(2011,2012,2013,2010,2011,2012,2013,2012,2013),
                 points=c(45,69,79,53,13,12,11,89,91),
                 result = c(2,3,5,4,6,1,2,3,4))
```

But I want to make `df` as below:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2,2,3),
                 year=c(2011,2012,2010,2011,2012,2012),
                 points=c(45,69,53,13,12,89),
                 result = c(3,5,6,1,2,4))
```

Here, I want to do some regression with the response variable `result`. Since I want to estimate `result`, I have to delay the response variable `result` and leave the other dependent variable `points`. So, for my regression setting, `result` is the response variable and `points` is the dependent variable. In summary, I want to do time lag for `result`. Within each id, each last row should be removed because, there are no next `result`.
I simplified my problem for demonstration purpose. Is there any way to achieve this using R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(lead_result = lead(result)) %>% na.exclude

# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   id [3]
     id  year points result lead_result
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>       <dbl>
1     1  2011     45      2           3
2     1  2012     69      3           5
3     2  2010     53      4           6
4     2  2011     13      6           1
5     2  2012     12      1           2
6     3  2012     89      3           4
```

Comment: Another option for removing `NA` rows would be to use `... %>% drop_na(lead_result)`. `na.exclude` will remove any row containing an `NA`; whereas, `drop_na` will only remove rows with an `NA` in the `lead_result` column.

Comment: @AndrewGB thanks for the pointer. I didn't consider it for this simple example, but there is definitely value in using a function with more control like `drop_na`.

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)

na.omit(setDT(df)[, result := shift(result, type = "lead"), by = "id"], "result")
```

**Output**

```
      id  year points result
   <num> <num>  <num>  <num>
1:     1  2011     45      3
2:     1  2012     69      5
3:     2  2010     53      6
4:     2  2011     13      1
5:     2  2012     12      2
6:     3  2012     89      4
```